# Installation XCode is not recognized by installer

Tags: install, xcode, catalina

I'm trying to install the [Free Pascal Compiler for Intel 3.0.5](https://www.freepascal.org/down/i386/macosx-hungary.var)

Althouth XCode and Xcode its command line tools are already installed (which I already use and which was already recognized by some other installations), it is not recognized by the installer of Free Pascal:

[image]

Is there any workaround to avoid this error? Is there something like `PATH` we have to set like in Windows?